# Eigenfunctions of Laplacian on sphere - numerical approach

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider a Laplacian:
$$\hat L=\frac1{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right)+\frac1{\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\varphi^2},$$
where $\theta\in[0,\pi], \varphi\in[0,2\pi)$.

I know that its eigenvalue problem (with boundary conditions as periodic in $\varphi$ and bounded in $\theta$) can be solved by separation of variables and the solution is [spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics). Now however, I'm interested in treating this problem numerically (because I need to later be able to solve eigenvalue problem for $\hat L+U(\theta,\varphi)$).

I want to use a grid method like finite differences for this.

What I found is that for $\theta\to0$ and $\theta\to\pi$ coefficients go to infinity as $\cot\theta$ for first part and $\csc^2\theta$ for second one. So, using a grid method, I have to reduce $\theta$ domain to some $[\varepsilon,\pi-\varepsilon]$. This of course still leads to bad representation of $\cot$ and $\csc^2$ at ends. So, I try to substitute $\cot\theta=z$, then $\csc^2\theta=z^2+1$ to have more fine discretization near poles.

Now new Laplacian looks like
$$\hat {L^\prime}=(z^2+1)^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}+z(z^2+1)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}+(z^2+1)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\varphi^2}.$$
Here $z\in(-\infty,\infty)$; for numerical treatment I replace infinities with some $z_{max}$. Now I mostly successfully solve this problem, BUT: it appears that although it's enough for $\varphi$ to have 10 points on grid, for $z$ even 300 points gives too low precision, whatever $z_{max}$ I select (though of course, getting them higher gives better accuracy, and $z_{max}$ has to be selected not too big and not too small to discretize space near poles and far from them equally well).

At the same time, the exact eigenfunctions look *really* simple and looking at them I wouldn't even think there's some difficulty at poles. This makes me think there must be much simpler way to solve this problem than using that many points in $\theta$.

**So, my question:** is there a good way to transform $\hat L$ so that discretization with small number of points in $\theta$ would give good accuracy - similar to what I have for $\varphi$ now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any parameterization of the sphere is going to have regions of high angle or area distortion.

Why do you need a regular grid? I would discretize the sphere as a triangle mesh, and then use the cotan-weight discrete Laplace-Beltrami operator (see chapter 6 of http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~keenan/Projects/DGPDEC/paper.pdf).